# Determining position of KendoUI DataViz Chart plot area

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

I have a screen where I need to align other controls with the plot lines of a DataViz chart control.

Using Javascript, how can I get the position of the PlotArea of the chart? I'd like to know the offset.left of the chart's plot area and the total PlotArea.width.

None of the properties / methods exposed in JavaScript are apparent.